# How to fix the issue "ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples" in Python

Tags: classification, text-classification, supervised-learning

I have two files namely `data` [3806, 2] and `target` [4039, 2]. My aim is split these files into training and testing datasets. I have already tried doing:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
data_train, data_test, target_train, target_test = train_test_split(data, target, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
```

However, it gives the error:

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [3806, 4039]
```

What is the optimal solution for this issue in order to run the classification algorithms?

Answer (score 1):

"train and test data sets are not equal in size:"

I presume you have already completed generating an X features and y label of sets
that has the same amount of data in them.  If not check that step again!

For example:

```
features = Sample_Set.drop('X', axis=1)
labels = Sample_Set['X']
```

Now, you'll generate your X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test

*** Don't forget train_test_split can only split the dataset into two.
So with this step, you generate a training set from 33% of the data and the rest left for the validation and test sets are 67%. So it will be harder for you to split those.

Why don't you take test_size=0.4 so that you will have 60 % for training and left 40% for validation and testing that can easily be divided into half easily?

This we will have 60% of data as "train set" and 40 % of the data as "test set"

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, labels, test_size=0.4, random_state=42)
```

Change the test_size into 50% so that half is going to our "test set", and the other half is going to our "validation test"

```
X_test, X_val, y_test, y_val = train_test_split(X_test, y_test, test_size=0.5, random_state=42)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a confusion about what [`train_test_split`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) does: its goal is to split  the data between training and test set. Usually the input data is made of two arrays: `X` for the features, `y` for the labels, and the function randomly selects a given proportion of rows as test set, leaving the rest as training set. Example:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
```

The rows used for the test set are the same from `X` and `y`, so that the output arrays still contain the  correct label for each instance: for instance rows 3,5,6,8 are selected in both arrays, and the features for row 3 still correspond to the label for row 3. This is why **the two input arrays must have the same length**.

In your code you give two arrays which have different length, hence the error.

- Either you want to use one of the arrays as training set and the other as test set, in which case you don't need to call `train_test_split` since your data is already split.
- Or you want to randomly select a test set from the union of these two datasets, and in this case you should concatenate the rows of the two arrays before calling `train_test_split`.